# jQuery Disable checkbox with same value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So this has to be the easiest question of the day. I have below HTML structure where all input `checkbox` values must be unique.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14292" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
        </td>
        <td>Test User One</td>
        <td>Autobot</td>
        <td>Shadow</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>

 <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14293" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
        </td>
        <td>Test User One</td>
        <td>Autobot</td>
        <td>Billed</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14292" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
        </td>
        <td>Test User Two</td>
        <td>Autobot</td>
        <td>Billed</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
```

The value `14292` is generated twice here.

1. How can I disable `checkbox` with duplicate value
2. How can I disable `checkbox` with `<td>Shadow</td>`

Comment: On what condition you want to disable duplicate checkbox?

Comment: if duplicate checkbox values. But that has to be on attribute `<td>Shadow</td>`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I have edited my answer to fit your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the `disabled` attribute to the next occurrences of checkboxes with the same value :

```
$('.chec_emp').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':enabled')) {
        $('.chec_emp[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9roLbu1L/1/)**

Comment: Brewal: The code works if the duplicate value is occuring next. But what if there is another `checkbox` between two `checkboxes` with same value ?

Comment: You can try it, but it should work. At each iteration, it looks for all other checkboxes with the same value. ("Other" beeing `.not(this)`)

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I updated the demo with your new html

Comment: Brewal: When I do `select all` to select all `checkboxes`, the `disabled` checkbox also displays `selected` Also one can change the disabled property from `console` and can again select it

Comment: What do you mean by `select all` ?

Comment: user has provision to select all the checkboxes using select all checkbox

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. `select all` with jQuery ? Anyway. **You should not trust data coming from client side** so if you go this way, one can add any field of any type he wants in the form. Javascript is just here for UX purposes

Comment: You will need to change your code for the "select all" checkbox. Something like `$('.chec_emp:enabled').click();` instead of  `$('.chec_emp').click();`

Comment: Code to select all checkboxes `$("#chec_all").click(function() {
            if ($("#chec_all").is(':checked'))
                $('input[class=chec_emp]').prop('checked', true);
            else
                $('input[class=chec_emp]').prop('checked', false);
        });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75509/discussion-between-brewal-and-slimshadddyyy).